# Can this be solved even faster?

Tags: equation-solving, performance-tuning

So I would like to solve the following set of equation for $m_i$ given a set of ${M_m,N_m}$.

$$
m_1 +m_2 +m_3 +m_4 =M_m \\
|m_1| +|m_2| +|m_3| +|m_4| =N_m
$$

All variables are integers. 
Also $N_m \ge M_m$ and their maximum value can reach up-to 30.
I only need the total number of possible solution not the solutions themselves. So my first trivial attempt was to just use `Solve`

```
dimNM1[Nm_, Mm_] :=
Length[(Solve[m1 + m2 + m3 + m4 == Mm && 
 Abs[m1] + Abs[m2] + Abs[m3] + Abs[m4] == Nm, {m1, m2, m3, m4}, Integers])]
```

My second slightly non-trivial attempt is the following:-

```
dimNM2[Nm_, Mm_] :=
Which[Nm === Mm, 
  Length[Partition[
Flatten[Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[Nm, {4}, Range[0, Nm]]], 
4]], True,
 Module[{res},
res = Partition[
 Flatten[Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[Mm, {4}, Range[-Nm, Nm]]],
  4];
  Length[
Select[res, (Abs[#[[1]]] + Abs[#[[2]]] + Abs[#[[3]]] + 
     Abs[#[[4]]]) == Nm &]]]]
```

The second method is much faster than the first specially for $N_m=M_m$. 
But I would like to increase the speed further for $N_m\ge M_m$ case if possible.

```
dimNM1[2, 2] // AbsoluteTiming
(*{0.177768, 10}*)

dimNM2[2, 2] // AbsoluteTiming
(*{0.0000899056, 10}*)
```

So is there any other way to solve these equation faster?

Comment: Note that `N` has built-in meanings.

Comment: OK I have changed it.

Comment: Nice problem. No need to generate candidates... see my reply.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
ClearAll[num];

num[n_, m_] /; OddQ[n + m] = 0;
num[n_, n_] := Binomial[n + 3, 3];
num[n_, m_] /; OddQ[n] := With[{z = Ceiling[m/2]}, (5*n^2 + 3)/2 + 2 z - (2 z^2)];
num[n_, m_] /; EvenQ[n] := With[{z = Ceiling[m/2]}, (5*n^2 + 4)/2 - (2 z^2)];
```

Testing vs fastest answer here at writing (Henrik Schumacher):

```
stop = 100;

res = Table[{n, m, dimNM3[n, m]}, {n, 1, stop}, {m, 1, n}]; // AbsoluteTiming//First
res2 = Table[{n, m, num[n, m]}, {n, 1, stop}, {m, 1, n}]; // AbsoluteTiming//First

res == res2
```

> 169.203
>
> 0.0219434
>
> True

Large cases are a non-issue:

```
num[123423456, 123412348] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.0000247977, 30468069908023290}

Some quick timings:

[image]

Comment: Pretty impressive. Would you mind to elaborate where these formulas come from or at least to provide an (accessible) source?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher - I derived them, looking at a set of results: I recognized the pattern(s). Neat that the tetrahedral numbers and coordination sequences popped out. See e.g. Sloan, "Low-Dimensional Lattices VII: Coordination Sequences".

Comment: Chapeaux for recognizing the patterns! =D

Comment: @ciao - You Sir are a genius. Thank you.

Comment: Answers from ciao are generally great reads, +1.

Answer (score 13):

It is more efficient to first pick the integer partitions whose absolute values sum up to `n` before generating the permutations.

```
dimNM3[n_, m_] := Total[
   Map[
    Length@*Permutations,
    Pick[#, Abs[#].ConstantArray[1, 4], n] &[
     IntegerPartitions[m, {4}, Range[-n, n]
      ]
     ]
    ]
   ];

m = 20;
n = 40;
dimNM1[n, m] // AbsoluteTiming
dimNM2[n, m] // AbsoluteTiming
dimNM3[n, m] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.116977, 3802}
>
> {0.995365, 3802}
>
> {0.005579, 3802}

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for not knowing much Mathematica, but I have a Python solution you might be able to follow. I'm putting this on the community wiki for anyone who wants to translate it.

```
def count_solutions(Nm, Mm):
    firsthalves = dict()
    for m1 in range(-Nm,Nm+1):
        for m2 in range(-Nm,Nm+1):
            m = m1+m2
            n = abs(m1)+abs(m2)
            key = (m,n)
            if key in firsthalves:
                firsthalves[key] += 1
            else:
                firsthalves[key] = 1

    solutions = 0
    for m3 in range(-Nm,Nm+1):
        for m4 in range(-Nm,Nm+1):
            m = m3+m4
            n = abs(m3)+abs(m4)
            key = (Mm-m, Nm-n)
            if key in firsthalves:
                solutions += firsthalves[key]
    return solutions
```

This is a meet in the middle strategy. I enumerate all the possible $m1,m2$ combinations and record how many times each $m1+m2,|m1|+|m2|$ combination occurs in a dictionary.

Then I go through all the possible $m3,m4$ combinations and for each combination I calculate the necessary $m1+m2,|m1|+|m2|$ combination to make $Mm,Nm$, and I refer to the dictionary to find out how many $m1,m2$ combinations can make that.

The difference is that you go through the $m1,m2$ combination then the $m3,m4$ combinations, and the number of operations is roughly a square root of going through every $m1,m2,m3,m4$ combination. You should be able to solve for $Nm = 1000,Mn = 0$ in a few seconds.

Answer (score 2):

A different approach, tied to @Hubble7's other question, that has the same speed as @ciao's answer. The key is in noting the sum of the negative numbers and sum of the nonnegative numbers are each fixed values, and so it is just a counting problem when we have 1 negative and 3 nonnegative terms, then 2 and 2, then 3 and 1. We can then use Mathematica's `NumberOfCompositions[ ]` function.

For values of `Mn` and `Nn` define

```
pos = (Nn+Mn)/2
neg = (Nn-Mn)/2
```

where `pos`is the sum of the positive numbers in `{m1, m2, m3, m4}` and `neg` is the sum of the absolute value of the negatives ( so it is a positive number).

Now use Mathematica's `NumberOfCompositions[n, k ]` function which gives you the count of all of the ways to divide integer `n` into `k` terms, including `0` terms. If we want to find the number of compositions not including `0` terms we calculate `NumberOfCompositions[n - k, k]`.

Note that for `k=1`, we have `NumberOfCompositions[n, 1] = 1`

If we have `k` negative terms, then we have `Binomial[4,k]` ways to arrange them. This is just `{4, 6, 4}` for `k = {1, 2, 3}`

So for values of `neg` and `pos`

```
perms = 4 * NumberOfCompositions[pos, 3] 
       + 6  NumberOfCompositions[neg - 2, 2] NumberOfCompositions[pos, 2] 
       + 4 NumberOfCompositions[neg - 3, 3]
```

And finally converting it into a function that accepts `Mn` and `Nm` ( while stealing some code from @ciao)

```
numNew[n_, m_] /; OddQ[n + m] = 0;
numNew[n_, n_] := Binomial[n + 3, 3];
numNew[n_, m_] := 4*NumberOfCompositions[(n + m)/2, 3]
                + 6*NumberOfCompositions[(n - m)/2 - 2, 2] NumberOfCompositions[(n + m)/2, 2] 
                + 4*NumberOfCompositions[(n - m)/2 - 3, 3]
```

Check the timing against @ciao's answer above

`num[123423456, 123412348] // AbsoluteTiming`

> {0.0000390021, 30468069908023290}

my function

`numNew[123423456, 123412348] // AbsoluteTiming`

> {0.0000369493, 30468069908023290}

It is about as fast as @ciao's and also suggests (to me!) an approach to this question:
[Find position without iterating](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/188495/find-position-without-iterating#188705)